# Using Java to input text on a website

Tags: java, asp.net, netbeans

I'm fairly new to Java so please bear with me.

The problem: Typing text into a webpage "text area" and hitting the "Post" Button using Java (netbeans IDE)

The fluff: I'm using Netbeans IDE at the moment for some Java projects at work. The idea behind my whole application is to ping an series of MS Access databases then report any errors to an internal "social media" website on our intranet.

I have the "pinging" element working, I'm struggling with the reporting errors to the website part.

I have full control over the databases but I only have access to the website via a good old browser and a link. The website is a .aspx (for example http://*mywebsite.intranet*/default.aspx) the text box is located on the default.aspx page, here is some of the info behind the text areas, not sure if this is useful to the cause or not.

```
<textarea id="status_ctl00_m_g_a871e14e_3f9d_4ea4_9452_fc5fce7321f4" rows="1"
maxlength="1900" title="What are you working on?" style="resize: none; overflow-
x:hidden; overflow-y: hidden; width: 508px; height: 36px; " autocomplete="off"
class="ac_input">What are you working on?</textarea>
```

And here is the info behind the button.

```
div class="ngPostButton"
    <button id="statusPost_ctl00_m_g_a871e14e_3f9d_4ea4_9452_fc5fce7321f4"
    class="ngButton"><span>Post</span></button>
```

Again, not sure if this is useful or not.

I have looked at a couple of solutions I've found on google, and I've managed to open the browser easily enough, but that's about as far as I got and I suspect the method used was a very basic one.

```
String[] cmd = { "C:\\Program Files\\Internet
Explorer\\IEXPLORE.exe","mywebsite.intranet\default.aspx};
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

I didn't want to post the code I have already as that runs ok and I didn't want to WALL OF TEXT anyone to death. Happy to post though if required.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could try that approach with the Robot class, or you could try Selenium.  However, if you're forced to only use I.E., you'll have to manually install the I.E. selenium driver on your machine.  The firefox driver only requires that firefox is installed.  Selenium: http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/  Robot: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html

Comment: I'll give Selenium a try thanks, I can use Firefox so will also try it with that. I did look at Selenium first, but I read a post saying it wasn't very useful for the task so I skipped past it, not seen anything about Robot class though so will give that a try too. Thanks! (still open for suggestions just in case I fail with either suggestion)

Comment: Since you have Ids of the elements you want, you basically just do, when you have a webdriver loaded to the URL you want: driver.findElement(By.id("")).sendKeys("type text here"); driver.findElement(By.id("")).click(); and that will type your stuff into the text area and click the button when you plug in the Ids, assuming they're real IDs.  Then you can scrape the page using the webdriver as well, using similar functionality.  I only suggested the Robot because it looked like you were going really low-level with it, I would use selenium personally.

Comment: Selenium and Robot are entirely the wrong approach IMO. What are you trying to do? You want your Java process to interact with the webpage, right? Doing so manually through a browser is the WRONG APPROACH. Why not simply send the HTML request from your Java? There's no reason to make Java use the browser!

Selenium and Robot are for testing. This is just communication.

You're making this WAY harder than it needs to be. Seriously, your program is going to launch Internet Explorer and control the mouse just to post updates? WHY?